# React Hooks - Why array destructuring over object destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've just started writing some custom hooks and the question popped up, should I return a set of values as an array or as an object?
Is there a specific reason that useState returns an array of a pair values and not an object with two properties?
I feel like I've read something about this but can't recollect where.
Thanks

Comment: Because it's easier for the user to name the array values.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [@Vishwas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025886/react-hooks-why-array-destructuring-over-object-destructuring#comment100581490_57025886), it has to do with naming.

This is briefly mentioned in the [fine print of the useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean).

> When we declare a state variable with `useState`, **it returns a pair — an array with two items**. The first item is the current value, and the second is a function that lets us update it. Using `[0]` and `[1]` to access them is a bit confusing because they have a specific meaning. This is why we use array destructuring instead.

```js
const [someValue, someUpdateFunction] = useState(0);
```

Under the hood React process the data at `array[0]` as the current value, and the data at `array[1]` as an update function. Only the position matters, not the naming. When devs implement `useState`, they can provide meaningful names to the values at those positions.